# Thread Sleep in Kestrel

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm playing with asp.net core web api project and I wanted to test few things. One was to artificially extend execution time of one controller endpoint. I used: Thread.Sleep(10000).

I'm using development Kestrel -> all standard stuff.

I know, this is not the best way to do that but I was surprised that when I tried to make another http request then it was waiting for first one to be completed. It is strange as I thought that ne thread will be spawned to handle another call in that situation.

I think that in IIS few years ago when I played with old ASP.Net it worked in a different way.

I'm not using any async/await, it is just a prototype and I don't want to solve any problem, Im just curious how does it work, Thanks for any explenation!

Comment: Are you using session state?

Comment: @StephenCleary No